# How to get the slots value in a Svelte component?

Tags: svelte

Say I created a component called Component, and I called it like this.

```
<Component>This text goes in the slot</Component>
```

Inside of the Component [I can use `<slot></slot>` to display that text in the html](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/slots). How can I reference its value in the script section? Is there a variable that it gets stored in?

Answer (score 10):

To get the slot content you need to apply a trick.

In your Component wrap the `slots` into a `span` and bind the elements using `bind:this`

In Component.svelte

```html
<script>
    let data;
    $: console.log(data?.innerHTML)
    $: console.log(data?.innerText)
</script>

<span bind:this={data}><slot></slot></span>
```

You can check it in this [repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/7c780140b089441193e55ca509e2bc92?version=3.44.0)

Comment: exactly , your can see also svelte documentation [here](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/slot-props)

Comment: Its not necessarily there is more elegant way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

I give below an example with named slots, also unnamed ->

**In Slot.svelte**

```
<script>
  let content ='lorem'
</script>


<slot name='named-slot' >
{content}
</slot>
```

**In Parent component**

```
<script>
 import Data from './Slot.svelte'
 let newData=' new content'
</script>

 
 <Data>  
 <svelte:fragment slot='named-slot' let:newData={content}>
  {newData} 
 </svelte:fragment>

 </Data>
```

*And exmaple for unnamed slot ->*

**In Slot.svelte**

```
<script>
      let content ='lorem'
    </script>
    
    <slot  >
    {content}
    </slot>
```

**In Parent component**

```
<script>
 import Data from './Slot.svelte'
 let newData=' new content'
</script>
    
 

 <Data let:newData={content}> 
  {newData}
   </Data>
```