# Use Svelte with Stencil components

Tags: javascript, svelte

we want to build an application with svelte but are stuck at using our components that we built with stenciljs.
At first it looked like it worked like a charm but as stencil components use the term "slot" and svelte does too, i am reveiving an error when using this component on svelte

> Element with a slot='...' attribute must be a child of a component or
> a descendant of a custom element

. I understand this issue, the question is how to ignore it or to tell svelte to ignore certain elements. Is there a function for that?

The component i try to use looks like that:

```html
<my-ui-image
  slot="image"
  src="/images/image.png"
  shadow-on-image="false"
  alt="image alt"
  title="Image title"
/>
```

Comment: The place to go in your case probably isn't StackOverflow. Consider searching for and eventually creating an issue here: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues

Comment: AFAIK `slot` semantically means the same for Svelte as for Stencil - you can only use it when you have a parent component that wraps `my-ui-image`. Is this not the case here? Could you enhance the snippet to show the full use case?

Comment: I am having the same issue. The issue is that 'slot="image"' needs to be in the DOM for the stencil component. But Svelte is seeing it "first" and throwing the error. We want svelte to basically ignore the 'slot="image"' attribute in this case.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So i tried this again and the issue is gone.

Answer (score 0):

check this post for named slots ->
[How to get the slots value in a Svelte component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69694079/how-to-get-the-slots-value-in-a-svelte-component/69694455#69694455)
I hope it gives you direction..